# Jquery hover function not working as intended

Tags: jquery, hover

I want to be enable users to view a full screenshot of a website I have developed and then when they hover over it another div fades in with some meta information.

Here is a test link - http://www.deanelliott.me/misc/test-port/index.html

As you can see, if you hover over the slideshow an overlay appears which is fine, but when you hover off it and the next slide comes into play the overlay is visible when it shouldn't be.

If anyone has any ideas on what the problem is that would be great!

Thanks

Edit: Here is the relevant code

```
$(function(){
$('#slideshow').hover(
    function(){
            $('.slideimage').fadeOut(100, function(){
                    $('.slideoverlay').fadeIn(100);                                            
            });
    },
    function(){
            $('.slideoverlay').fadeOut(100, function(){
                    $('.slideimage').fadeIn(100);                                           
            });
    }
    );
});
```

.slideoverlay is set to display:none via CSS

Comment: **Note:** It is customary to also post relevant code here. Try using [`fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/) instead of `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut()` I've had better luck with it. FadeIn/Out act strangely when used with other methods of show/hide.

Comment: you should probably post the relevant code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason your `fadeIn()` is getting applied to all of the slideoverlays but the `fadeOut()` only gets applied to the currently visible one. I would try to make it so that the `fadeIn()` and `fadeOut` only effect the actual one you are hovering over. Something like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#slideshow .slide').hover(
        function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.find('.slideimage').fadeOut(100, function(){
                $this.find('.slideoverlay').fadeIn(100);                                            
            });
        },
        function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.find('.slideoverlay').fadeOut(100, function(){
                $this.find('.slideimage').fadeIn(100);                                           
            });
        }
    );
});
```

Could probably use some optimization, but I'm thinking this should work. Haven't tested though, so good luck.

Try this to get rid of the white flash. Basically, the thought is you don't need to hide the `$('.slideimage')` if you're just overlaying the overlay over it. All you need to do is hide and show the slideoverlay.

```
$(function(){
    $('#slideshow .slide').hover(
        function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.find('.slideoverlay').fadeIn(100);                                            
        },
        function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            $this.find('.slideoverlay').fadeOut(100);
        }
    );
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thank you. Is there any way to stop the white "flash" that occurs during the transition?

Comment: See edit for getting rid of "white flash". Let me know how it works :)